# No keys present in RelayStateQuery

Tags: saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

In ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 implementation, `Saml2PostBinding` object has `SetRelayStateQuery()` and `GetRelayStateQuery()` methods to set and get data from dictionary.

Sometimes, `GetRelayStateQuery()` returns Empty dictionary even though I have set values using `SetRelayStateQuery()`. I am not able to reproduce this while testing but it is happening for many clients on production. In which scenarios may this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The SetRelayStateQuery() should be used in the RP (relying party) and then the GetRelayStateQuery() in the IdP (identity provider). The methods should not be used in the samme application.

You can trace the error by looking at the SAML send between the parties.

Comment: I use SetRelayStateQuery() in login method to set email id and GetRelayStateQuery() in ACS method to retrieve stored email id . If this is not the right approach, can you suggest to me how to set some values at login time and retrieve the same when the user request comes to the ACS method ? (both the methods are at Service Provider's end)

Comment: It sounds like the right approach regarding setting and reading a value. Usually through, the e-mail/user id is part of the claims received in the ACS method. You would usually save a redirect url or session id in the relay state.